# Field configuration in PivotGrid DevExreme

Tags: javascript, devexpress, devextreme

I am working with `PivotGrid` by `DevExtreme` in `Angular2`. Is it possible to define a field that is visible in the field chooser but it is not included in the pivot by default?

`visible: false` in field configuration will hide the field also from the chooser.

I haven't found useful information about this in their documentation https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_1/ApiReference/Data_Layer/PivotGridDataSource/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify the `area` option of the required field to achieve this.